# Best array of objects structure to sum values based on similar keys in a specific date range

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I'm learning so please bear with me if it's a silly question. I created the two following array of objects structures:

```
var dictionary1Bis = [
    {
        "2022-07-06": [
            {
                material: "1_1$bolsa",
                quantity: 23
            },
            {
                material: "1_2$m3",
                quantity: 2
            },
            {
                material: "1_7$unidad",
                quantity: 4
            }
        ],
        "2022-07-07": [
            {
                material: "1_1$bolsa",
                quantity: 3
            }
        ],
        "2022-07-08": [
            {
                material: "1_1$bolsa",
                quantity: 10
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

and:

```
var dictionary1Ter = [
    {
        date: "2022-07-06",
        material: "1_1$bolsa",
        quantity: 23
    },
    {
        date: "2022-07-06",
        material: "1_2$m3",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        date: "2022-07-06",
        material: "1_7$unidad",
        quantity: 4
    },
    {
        date: "2022-07-07",
        material: "1_1$bolsa",
        quantity: 3
    },
    {
        date: "2022-07-08",
        material: "1_1$bolsa",
        quantity: 10
    }
];
```

I'm trying to understand which is the best (and easier to manipulate) structure to sum all the quantities of the objects for which both the following statements are `TRUE`:

- `date <= "2022-07-07"`;
- `material = "1_1$bolsa"`.

Basically what I would like to get is:

```
result = [
    {
        material: "1_1$bolsa",
        quantity: 26
    },
    {
        material: "1_2$m3",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        material: "1_7$unidad",
        quantity: 4
    },
];
```

I have the feeling that `dictionary1Ter` is easier to deal with, am I wrong? Is there any better array of objects structure to achieve what I'm trying to do? Also, any hints on the next steps would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you written any code to sort through either of them?

Comment: dictionary1Ter looks a lot easier to work with, generally.

Comment: `dictionary1Bis` should not be an array containing a single object. In general, a lookup structure is better suited if you need to get the values for a single date, a (sorted!) array is better suited if you need to get a (larger) range of values.

Comment: @imvain2 Initially I tried using Array.map() on both `dictionary1Bis` and `dictionary1Ter` but I've been struggling to be honest. After having looked at the answer provided by @James (that, by the way, works perfectly), I'm trying again to use Array.map() to understand if I can achieve the same result. Now I can extract keys and values but I'm still trying to figure out what I have to do with them. Yes, you're right @Bergi, `dictionary1Bis` shouldn't be an array and thanks for the additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a reduce operation to sum those materials

```js
var dictionary1Ter = [
    {
        date: "2022-07-06",
        material: "1_1$bolsa",
        quantity: 23
    },
    {
        date: "2022-07-06",
        material: "1_2$m3",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        date: "2022-07-06",
        material: "1_7$unidad",
        quantity: 4
    },
    {
        date: "2022-07-07",
        material: "1_1$bolsa",
        quantity: 3
    },
    {
        date: "2022-07-08",
        material: "1_1$bolsa",
        quantity: 10
    }
];

var result = Object.values(
  dictionary1Ter.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (el.date <= "2022-07-07") {
      if (!acc[el.material]) 
        acc[el.material] = {material: el.material, quantity: 0};
        
      acc[el.material].quantity += el.quantity;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```